# Magento 2: Auto-Add Product and Ship to Separate Address

Tags: php, magento

I am looking into what I would need to give away a free sample product with every order on my Magento site that could be sent to a friend or family. Essentially what I need is to auto-add a product into the basket and then supply two different shipping addresses. I know that multiple address shipping is a built-in feature of Magento, but would this give me what I need or would it require dev work to completely configure? Same goes for the auto-add product.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a module in the magento backend to add the product to shopping cart, you can lean [here](https://mage2gen.com/) generator adapting it to what you need, or look for a paid module like [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-free-gifts/).